# Carousel ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having problems with making the carousel work on ASP.net page; the same code works on some other project, but it doesn't work in mine; is there something I might be missing?

I tried moving stuff around but it won't work, is it perhaps I haven't installed bootstrap properly?

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="~/images/BBQBeefRe.jpeg" alt="BBQ Beef" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; " />
                <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                    <h2>
                        BBQ Beef
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="~/images/ChiPiRe.jpg" alt="Chicken Pineapple" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" />
                <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                    <h2>
                        Chicken Pineapple
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="~/images/PepRe.jpg" alt="Pepperoni" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" />
                <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                    <h2>
                        Pepperoni
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="~/images/Vegre.jpg" alt="Vegetarian" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" />
                <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                    <h2>
                        Vegetarian
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: When it run the code it shows everything at once

Comment: This is just a page with lots of divs. To turn this into a carousal, you'll need JavaScript or some king of third party library.